# Iterate list using copy in ARM Template

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-deployment

I have an ARM template in which I provision a number of web apps. I want to add IP restrictions on these web apps allowing access only between theses. I can retrieve the IPs using:

```
reference(resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appName1')),'2015-08-01').PossibleOutboundIpAddresses
```

It's the following that I don't know how to solve in a good manner.

1. I have replaced the `resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appName1'))` part with a variable instead to shorten it a bit. Can I shorten it even more somehow? It becomes even more complex as you'll see soon.
2. I have created a resources section for each web app in which there is a properties section. In this section the ipSecurityRestrictions resides. As the PossibleOutboundIpAddresses returns a string I use split to create a list and copy to iterate the IP addresses. But it does not work for me and returns the following error message: 
   `The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified`

The section looks like this:

```
"resources": [
            {
                "type": "config",
                "name": "web",
                "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
                "properties": {
                    "copy": [
                        {
                            "name": "ipSecurityRestrictions",
                            "count": "[length(split(reference(variables('appName1'),'2015-08-01').PossibleOutboundIpAddresses, ','))]",
                            "input": {
                                "ipAddress": "[split(reference(variables('appName1'),'2015-08-01').PossibleOutboundIpAddresses, ',')[copyIndex('ipSecurityRestrictions')]]",
                                "subnetMask": "255.255.255.254"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                },
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appName1'))]"
                ]
            }
        ]
```

I feel like I follow all examples I can find online exactly.
Another problem with this is the many characters I'll have to write every time I want to reference the IP list. To make things worse, this list should be the merged one from all the provisioned web apps. So if I have 3 web apps the line is going to be incredible long and complicated.

3. Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, first question: can I make it shorter.
answer: it really depends, judging on what you show, not really (you can drop api-version if the resources are in the same template).

second question: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified.
answer: you cant do that, unfortunately (runtime\compile time drama). You'd have to use nested templates to achieve same outcome.

third question: Is there a better solution to this?
answer: probably. I'd create all 3 web apps as a nested deployment (NOT inline) and return an array of strings (similar to what you do)

```
"outputs" : {
    "array": {
         "type": "array",
         "value": "[split(reference(variables('appName')]"
    }
}
```

then I'd process those in a single run with concat and something like what you are doing (but this have to be in a nested template as  well). something like:

```
"[concat(reference('deployment1').outputs.array.value, reference('deployment2').outputs.array.value, reference('deployment3').outputs.array.value)]"
```

and then in the nested template you can do:

```
                "copy": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipSecurityRestrictions",
                        "count": "[length(parameters('myArray'))]",
                        "input": {
                            "ipAddress": "[parameters('myArray')[copyIndex('ipSecurityRestrictions')]]]",
                            "subnetMask": "255.255.255.254"
                        }
                    }
                ],
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. For the first question: I may have expressed it wrong: I meant if it's possible to shorten the expression that retrieves the list of IP addresses, but it seems like it's not the case.
For the second question: how come compile/run time messes up here? I depend on the web app which should be all I need, right?

Comment: 1. like i said, only way you can shorten it - drop api version: `split(reference(variables('appName1').PossibleOutboundIpAddresses, ',')`. 2. properties copy is a compile time function\construct. data for it has to exist at compile time. that means you can use reference inside that function\construct, because it has no data at compilation time, it will only get data once you run the template and it was able to pull it from the resource. workaround - nested templates. hint: if the resource is part of the same template - you dont need dependsOn. reference function implies dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have learned some important lessons from your comments. I'll accept your answer and look into nested deployments.

Comment: that's what I'm here for @Casper